# How does eddystone-url works?

Tags: android, google-chrome, eddystone, eddystone-url

Recently, I have just get an eddystone-url device and I can see the device from my android 4.4 phone using app like beacon scanner. From my understanding eddystone-url doesn't need an app for it to work. I have chrome installed on my phone but I don't see any notification at all from my phone when it receive eddystone-url signal.

How can I get eddystone-url to work on my phone without the need of any special app?

Comment: You absolutely do need an app for Eddystone-URL to work. Chrome and Google Play Services are apps that do the detection.

Comment: @davidgyoung Yeah, I have both Chrome and Google Play Services on my phone, but eddystone-url still does work.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely need an application to detect and explore Eddystone URL beacons. Thankfully one such application is Google Chrome. You have to turn this on in Chrome/Settings/Privacy/Physical Web. Few more permissions have to be granted as described in [Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6239299?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en). The Google Chrome shows a notification when it detects a beacon around.

Be aware that while you can configure any URL to beacon, not every URL works with Chrome. Chrome filters out some URLs using [rules](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/privacy/whitepaper.html#physical-web).

The other option is [Physical Web](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=physical_web.org.physicalweb&hl=en) application also from Google (or The Physical Web Team from Google). But you have to install this separately. The same rules applies and similar permissions are needed there. The difference is that this app supports also different channels than beacons.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/developer_faq.  Might be issue with your Nearby settings on your device (Settings/Google/Nearby)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't find nearby setting in my phone. All I have in Google setting page is Search, Location, and Ads.